# User selects city from options in form and pass longitude and latitude to api

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to pass longitude and latitude to the geonames api. Currently I have two select fields where a user selects the city longitude and the corresponding city latitude:

```
<select id="selectLat">
    <option value="30.26057">Chicago Latitude</option>
    <option value="51.5074">London Latitude</option>
    <option value="50.0755">Prague Latitude</option>
    
</select>

<select id="selectLng">
    <option value="-97.771889">Chicago Longitude</option>
    <option value="0.1278">London Longitude</option>
    <option value="14.4378">Prague Longitude</option>
</select>
```

Once selections are submitted the values are passed to the geonames api and I'm able use the JSON data returned. But what I actually want to happened is that a user simply selects the city name only. The longitude and latitude values would be combined and are then somehow parsed/separated and passed to the api. Are there ways to do this?

I'm using jQuery and php to handle the api request btw.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                 lat: $('#selectLat').val(),
                 lng: $('#selectLng').val()
            },
```

Comment: I assume these values come from a database. So you could only present a single select with the city name and use the id to retrieve the lat and long values from the database inside your AJAX script.

Comment: You mean you want a dropdown list of cities, and then a lookup table containing the longitude and latitude of each city?

Comment: You could combine them by using a delimiter such as the pipe (|) e.g. `<option value="30.26057|-97.771889">Chicago</option>` then in the PHP script you can extract the longitude and latitude values using `explode` e.g. `explode('|', $value)`

Comment: Yes a dropdown list of cities and I would just hardcode the longitude and latitude.

Comment: El_vanja's solution seems like the obvious one then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `data-` attributes, eg:

```
<option data-longitude="..." data-latitude="...">city</option>
```

then

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
             lat: $('#citySelect option:selected').data("latitude"),
             lng: $('#citySelect option:selected').data("longitude"),
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain an array so that you have for each city its longitude and latitude,
When selecting a city you will remove the information from the array from the array.

HTML:

```
 <select id="select_city">
                <option value="chicago">Chicago Latitude</option>
                <option value="london">London Latitude</option>
                <option value="prague">Prague Latitude</option>
                
        </select>
```

JS:

```
 const c = "{'prague' : {'latitude': 50.0755, 'longitude': 14.4378}, 'london': {'latitude': 50.0755, 'longitude':14.4378}}";
 .
 .
 .
 lat = c[${'#select_city').val()].latitude;
 lng = c[${'#select_city').val()].longitude;

  $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                 lat: lat,
                 lng: lng
            },
```